# How to get the number of users logged in in the firebase database (Without addValueEventListener() )?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been looking for this quite some time now and i haven't found any answer related to my problem, so before you tag my question duplicate, at least read it first.
First i have just started firebase and only know basic things about it, i am trying to make a simple single user (1 to 1) chat app.
I want to get the number of users logged in in the database.

I have a child to the root of my database called users which have the list of the users who have logged in.
[image: i have a child to the root of my database called users which have the list of the users who have logged in.]
I know about the datashot.getchildrencount() but that works when some update/event happens, but **i want it to give me the number of users whenever i want, not only on some event** (For example in messenger number of current active users are shown continuously,i dont want active user tho, i just want total logged in users).
I thought of the another way to make a child called NumberofUsers so i store number of users there but then firebase dont allow to getvalue of the child,only set value (it does allow to get value but only on some event). Any idea what should i do?

**UPDATE**
i thought of another way to do this, though its not working at the moment but i think solving it is easier than thinking of another method to solve my original problem.
so I made one more child of NumberofUsers with key "02" and random value. now everytime i want data of "01" i change the value "02" after enabling the addChildEventListener for "NumberofUsers".  Code that does this. [image: Code that does this]Error its giving me. [image: Error its giving me].new database. [image: new database] 
Apparently I cant access child data using datasnapshot, any solution?
Any idea how to solve either of this?
Thank you.

Comment: You cannot read data from the Firebase Database without attaching a listener. But when you attach a listener, it fires  for the current data. I recommend you try attaching a listener, see if that gives you the result you want. If it doesn't, post back here with the code and we'll be in a much better spot to help.

Comment: as you have mentioned in a comment in this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279329/how-firebase-listener-actually-work)    listener only works when database updates. yes i do want it to listen too but later, at the start i want to tell the users how many other users are logged in. for that there will be no event for listener to catch. my question is somewhat related to this one but its not answered too. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184797/retrieve-data-from-firebase-database-on-button-click).  what part of code you want me to post?

Comment: I know you cant directly read the data from database, but still is there any way around that you know of? i just want to get data, (add 1 to it and set it  with new value in case of a new account )....

Comment: Nowhere in that link do I say it only fires for changes. In fact: "The server adds that listener to a list of all listeners of all connected clients. **It then also sends back the initial data for that listeners.**" Try it. If it doesn't work, show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way in which you can read data from a Firebase Database without attaching a listener. Regarding Firebase, everything it's about listeners. In your case, i think you want a callback to be called once and then immediately removed. If so, i recomand you using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method to simplify this scenario. It triggers once and then does not trigger again.

This is useful for data that only needs to be loaded once and isn't expected to change frequently or require active listening.

Hope it helps.